# Get rows from table in DB using SQL

Tags: sql

I want to get rows from database. I am using the following query:

```
select * from Table where  columnB = '1' AND '3';
```

I want to get rows in which `column A` has the same value and `columnB` is either 1 and 3. I don't want any single row of `columnA`.

I want to retrieve rows in pairs on the basis of value in column A. There should no single row with value of column A

Comment: Do you mean `columnb is either 1 OR 3`?  It can't be two values at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Still not sure I understand your question, but...

if you want **all rows with B='1' such that there's also another row with B='3' and both rows have the same value of A**, as well as **all rows with B='3' such that there's also another row with B='1' and both rows have the same value of A**, then something like this should work:

```
select * from Table as t1
where columnB = '1'
  and exists (
    select * from Table as t2
    where t2.columnA = t1.columnA
      and t2.columnB = '3'
  )
UNION
select * from Table as t3
where columnB = '3'
  and exists (
    select * from Table as t4
    where t4.columnA = t3.columnA
      and t4.columnB = '1'
  )
```

Your output will be something like this:

```
| ColumnA | ColumnB |
|   foo   |    1    |
|   foo   |    3    |
|   bar   |    1    |
|   bar   |    3    |
|   cat   |    1    |
|   cat   |    3    |
```

Comment: You can use 'order by' to sort your results.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly

```
SELECT columnA, columnB 
FROM Table
WHERE columnA = 'SOME_VALUE'
  AND columnB IN ('1', '3')
```

Comment: In this way i would also get those rows which has columnA='SOME_VALUE' and columnB has 1 or 3.But i want two rows everytime in which columnA='SOME_VALUE' and columnB has 1 and 3